# Chrome Extension Ajax Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, google-chrome-extension

I am a newbie and working on a google-chrome extension, that needs to make jquery ajax requests to a server, load some html documents . My server is Apache, running on localhost using **XAMPP 1.7.3**. an the jquery is **jquery-1.6.1.js**.

When I load it using standard browser like chrome like http://localhost/Chrome/popup.html, the jquery ajax works. And it loads the html documents funtionaly. But, the problem is when I open my extension by "Load unpacked extension" in Google Chrome **(Google Chrome 11)** extension developer mode. *The html document won't load*.

Anyone can help solving my ploblem?

this is my code :

manifest.json

```
        {
        "name": "Nyu Extension",
        "version": "1.0",
        "description": "My First Extension",
        "permissions" : ["http://localhost/", "http://*/*"],
        "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "N.png",
        "popup": "popup.html"
        }
        }
```

popup.html

```
        ...
        function activeTab(tab)
        {   
            document.getElementById("tab1").className = "";
            document.getElementById("tab"+tab).className = "active";           
            if(tab == 1)
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "ssc/contentpage1.txt",
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#content').html(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        ...
```

please tell me if anything wrong..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should specify an absolute (full) URL in the $.ajax call (i.e. http://localhost/Chrome/ssc/contentpage1.txt).